# scrolling finish callback in Line Chart Android

Tags: android, graph, charts, line

In my application, I have to display Line chart.
So, I am using **MPAndroidChart** for displaying line chart and have implemented successfully but I need to perform some action on scroll finish.

Please help me to solve my issue.

Comment: Did you find solution for this ? I exactly need the same implementation